# Is it possible to use a String as a calculation?

Tags: java, string, user-interface, math, input

i am a beginner in Jave and i am trying to develop a program which uses the cesar algorithm for encryption.

```
String Text;
String encryptedText = "";
char character;
int n;

Text = mainprogramm.tainput.getText();
int length = Text.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    character = Text.charAt(i);
    n = (int) character;
    encryptedText = encryptedText + (char) tencryptingformula.getText();
}
```

tencryptedformula is a text field in which a calculation is written: eg. 2*n+1. If I type this formula directly into my code it encrypts it probably. However I am not able make it accept my String as the formula. It gives the error: "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Char". How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the same way you're looping through `Text`, loop through each character in `tencryptingformular`.

Comment: Do you want to use the formula to encrypt your text? Please have a look at a dictionary first, as "formular" is not an english word.

Comment: May I understood wrong but are you trying to concatenate the formula within the text field to the `encryptedText` variable? In that case use simply `encryptedText += tencryptingformular.getText();`

Comment: The program doesn't make much sense. It would be better if you try explaining how you are implementing caesar encryption in the code. What are character and n? Zeichen is assigned and never used. What does tencryptingformular.getText() do?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are trying to turn a string into a computation. You can't simply enter a string and expect Java to automatically recognise what you want to do with it.

If you're asking what I think, you'd need to parse the string to explicitly pull out the algebraic terms and replace the operators programmatically. It'd be much easier to have this directly in your code and maybe provide the option to switch between different formulas; instead of trying to write a parser to evaluate any generic expression.

Comment: ok, is there any way to write such a program or could you link an instruction?

Comment: You could write it yourself, otherwise do some googling and I'm sure you can find a library or some resources to help you.

Comment: @ashold7 Asking for libraries is off-topic here. See the sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly evaluate a String as a mathematical expression in Java (it's a compiled language). You'd have to write your own parser for that, which is actually quite a lot of work, and it also has already been done by other people.

So another approach is to call an interpreted language from Java, e.g. by using 
JavaScript through the [`ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html). So what you can do is let the user enter the formula in some textfield, retrieve the text and evaluate it by putting the decimal value of a character into the formula, which returns you the decimal value of the encrypted character.

Example (<del>untested</del> tested):

```
// The formula wich encrypts characters, e.g. "2*n+1".
String expression = textfieldFormula.getText();
ScriptEngine interpreter = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");

String textToEncrypt = textfieldInput.getText();
String encryptedText = "";

String encryptedText = "";

for (int i = 0; i < textToEncrypt.length(); i++) {
   int unencrypted = textToEncrypt.charAt(i);
   interpreter.put("n", unencrypted);
   try {
      // Calculate the result now that n is set.
      Object result = interpreter.eval(expression);
      // result is a double which we need to cast, or round.
      int encryptedChar = (int) Double.parseDouble(result.toString());
      encryptedText += (char) encryptedChar;
   } catch (ScriptException ex) {
      System.err.println("Cannot evaluate: " + expression);
      // Handle unevaluateable formula here…
   }
}
```

You might need to add some minor modifications to adapt the snippet to your needs.

Cheers